# Much time to get answer from my local webserver in InputStream method

Tags: java, android, webserver, inputstream

guys. I am trying to get some content from my local web server runnning on a ESP8266 module(It is working as an access point and I am connecting my phone directly to it - I have already tested this through my browser and works perfectly). The problem is when my code gets in InputStream method because it takes so much time (about 2 or 3 minutes) to get answer on my logcat from the local server. But one curious thing is that when a get out from the APP and go to my browser on the phone and updates it the server immediately responds and the content is displayed on my logcat. My code and logcat are:

```
        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();               //It seems the problem is here
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            Log.i("analog content", "here2");
            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }
            Log.i("analog content", result);
            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not find weather :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return null;
        }
```

My logcat:

20-05-19 13:06:46.396 32406-32415/com.example.myapplication I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=23KB

2020-05-19 13:06:46.396 32406-32415/com.example.myapplication I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB

2020-05-19 13:06:46.440 32406-32465/com.example.myapplication I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so from the current namespace instead.

2020-05-19 13:06:46.629 32406-32406/com.example.myapplication W/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring

2020-05-19 13:06:46.635 32406-32406/com.example.myapplication I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2348 bytes, containing 1 windows, 9 views

2020-05-19 13:07:00.697 32406-32406/com.example.myapplication I/analog content: here1

2020-05-19 13:07:00.729 32406-32543/com.example.myapplication I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor

2020-05-19 13:07:00.788 32406-32543/com.example.myapplication D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

2020-05-19 13:07:15.340 32406-32415/com.example.myapplication I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=59KB, data=54KB

2020-05-19 13:07:15.340 32406-32415/com.example.myapplication I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=59KB, data=54KB

2020-05-19 13:07:15.340 32406-32415/com.example.myapplication I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB

2020-05-19 13:07:16.908 32406-32415/com.example.myapplication I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 6MB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()

2020-05-19 13:07:55.517 32406-32415/com.example.myapplication I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=125KB, data=92KB

2020-05-19 13:07:55.518 32406-32415/com.example.myapplication I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=87KB, data=59KB

2020-05-19 13:08:56.425 32406-32543/com.example.myapplication I/analog content: here2

2020-05-19 13:08:56.440 32406-32543/com.example.myapplication I/analog content: {
      "analog": [
        "Tudo bem"
      ],
      "digital": [
        5
      ]
    }
2020-05-19 13:09:09.281 32406-32417/com.example.myapplication I/zygote64: System.exit called, status: 1

2020-05-19 13:09:09.281 32406-32417/com.example.myapplication I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 1, cleanup skipped.

As you see I get the answer (on logcat line 2020-05-19 13:08:56.440) but it takes too much or until I go my browser and updates it.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Where do you close your inputstream?

Comment: Hi,  Thorbjørn Ravn ! I have already solved the problem. Thank you a lot the same way  for trying to help me. In fact my problem was on my ESP8266 webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved my problem that was in fact on my ESP8266 webserver because it was not anwering the client correctly.I made many confusions there as I was working with JSON.
Thank you all.